# NGXS and Angular: Canceling previous requests on http calls

Tags: angular, ngxs

I am trying to get to grips with NGXS for angular.

I am trying to follow this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SGj11j4hxmg&t=358s, (the example starts at 10:16), here he discusses how to use { cancelUncompleted: true }. I have also read up on it here https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/cancellation

So far it seems to be working, however I am not sure if the previous script is cancelled.

My code looks like this.
The **post.state.ts** file

```
@Action(SendDataApi, { cancelUncompleted: true })
fetchData(
    { patchState, getState }: StateContext<DataState>,
    { payload }: SendDataApi
): object {
    const theState = getState();
    const url = payload.url;
    const reload = payload.reload;
    const data = {};

    // // // check to see data is saved, if so return
    if (_.has(theState, url) && !reload) {
        if (!_.isEmpty(theState[url])) {
            if (!_.has(theState[url], 'status')) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    // // add a pending status while getting data
    if (_.isUndefined(data[url])) {
        data[url] = {};
    }

    data[url] = { status: 'pending' };
    patchState(data);

    // if success, return with folder structure
    const storeData = (success: {}, isSuccess: boolean): DataState => {
        data[url] = isSuccess ? success : { status: 'error' };
        return data;
    };

    return this.postService.postData(payload).pipe(
        tap(success =>
            success
                ? patchState(storeData(success, true))
                : patchState(storeData(success, false))
        ),
        delay(1000)
    );
}
```

The **postService.service.ts** file

```
/** ignore dataToSend as testing only **/
postData(payload: { url: string; dataToSend: {} }): Observable<unknown> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.appUrl}` + payload.url);
}
```

The **component.component.ts** file

```
this.store
        .dispatch(
            new SendDataApi({
                url: apiUrl,
                data: dataToSend,
            })
        )
        .subscribe(
            data => console.log(data),
            error => console.log(error)
        );
```

However in the video, the console log shows calls and then cancellations but my console log shows like this. It seems to indent over and over. **Am I actually cancelling the previous request?**
I dont want to add any memory leaks or any thing slowing the app down.

[image]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Not sure if this matters, but you've type your action as returning an object... fetchData(): object; You should be return an Observable<T>; As long as the Observable is still in flight, it will be canceled. In the video he is chaining actions together, and if one fails he wants it to be cancelled. My use case is normally like a typeahead. I dispatched some text, but before the action can complete, I dispatch more text. So it cancels the previous dispatched action and starts over. This is basically the way switchMap works: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply, You are right, It does return an Observable. That is is fixed! I will look into the chaining, and see transpires. Thanks for the tip.